# No signature of method: java.lang.String.getCatalogName() is applicable for argument

Tags: java, oracle, methods, groovy

I am receiving the following error when using `getCatalogName()` method. I am sure I am making a silly mistake (might be the format). Can you please suggest what I am missing here.

**Error Details :**

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.getCatalogName() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

**Code :**

```
def Phys11 = "1Q"
def String str45 = Phys11.getCatalogName()
println 'HP' + Str
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `getCatalogName` supposed to be?

Comment: show us the getCatalogName method definition

Comment: Kindly refer the below **link :https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e17060/oracle/odi/domain/topology/OdiPhysicalSchema.html#getCatalogName__**

Comment: That returns a String from a `OdiPhysicalSchema` object, and isn't a method on a String

Answer (score 4):

`Phys11` refers to the `String` `1Q` and the class `String` doesn't have any method called `getCatalogName()` that is why you get this exception.

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone ! What I am trying to achieve here is pass the schema name and pick the corresponding  catalog name in my Oracle Data Integrator application (ODI).

Comment: this sounds like a different question so you should create a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

Ananda,

**getCatalogName** is not at all a method from the String class (that you are trying to call).

From the link you gave it is a method of **oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiPhysicalSchema** class
who returns the name of the physical schema as a String.

I suppose you should call this getCatalogName method from a reference to the OdiDataServer you are connected to.

And may be you should also post/tag your question to the 'oracle-data-integrator' forum ?